# D3 Filter Issue

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to filter my data list using D3.  What I am trying to do is filter my data based on date I specify and threshold value for precipitation.

Here is my code as

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
        //var currentDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" )/1000;
        //console.log(currentDate)
    });
}); 


function GenerateReport() {
    d3.csv("/DataTest.csv", function(data) {
        var startdate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" )/1000;

        var enddate =  startdate + 24*60*60

        var data_Date = d3.values(data.filter(function(d) { return d["Date"] >= 
            startdate && d["Date"] <= enddate} ))

        var x = document.getElementById("threshold").value
        console.log(data_Date)
        var data_Date_Threshold = data_Date.filter(function(d) {return 
            d.Precipitation > x});
```

My data set looks like

```
ID        Date      Prcip  Flow Stage
1010    1522281000     0    0   0
1010    1522281600     0    0   0
1010    1522285200     10   0   0
1010    1522303200     12   200 1.2
1010    1522364400     6    300 2
1010    1522371600     4    400 2.5
1010    1522364400     6    500 2.8
1010    1522371600     4    600 3.5
2120    1522281000     0    0   0
2120    1522281600     0    0   0
2120    1522285200     10   100 1
2120    1522303200     12   1000    2
2120    1522364400     6    2000    3
2120    1522371600     4    2500    3.2
2290    1522281000     0    0   0
2290    1522281600     4    0   0
2290    1522285200     5    200 1
2290    1522303200     10   800 1.5
2290    1522364400     6    1500    3
2290    1522371600     0    1000    2
6440    1522281000     0    0   0
6440    1522281600     4    0   0
6440    1522285200     5    200 0.5
6440    1522303200     10   800 1
6440    1522364400     6    1500    2
6440    1522371600     0    100 1.4
```

When I use filter function, I have some problems.
What I have found is that when I use x = 2 to filter precipitation value, it does not catch precipitation = 10 or 12.  However, when I use x=1, it works fine. I am guessing that it catches only the first number (e.g., if x=2, it regards precipitation = 10 or 12 is less than 2 since it looks only 1 in 10 and 12) Is there anyone who had the same issue what I have?  Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why screenshot the code when you could copy the code into your post?

Comment: Try adding the following `console.log(typeof d.Precipitation, d.Precipitation, typeof x, x)` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks. I just replaced the screenshots with actual codes.

Comment: string 0 string 2
string 10 string 2
string 12 string 2
string 0 string 2
string 10 string 2
string 12 string 2
string 0 string 2
string 4 string 2
string 5 string 2
string 10 string 2
string 0 string 2
string 4 string 2
string 5 string 2
string 10 string 2                 This is what I see.

Comment: Thank you so much. I converted these numbers into numeric from string and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing **strings**. This comparison is therefore done [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

In order to accomplish what you want, you need to first convert these strings to numbers:

```
var x = Number(document.getElementById("threshold").value)
var data_Date_Threshold = data_Date.filter(function(d) {return Number(d.Precipitation) > x});
```

Alternatively, floats:

```
var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("threshold").value)
var data_Date_Threshold = data_Date.filter(function(d) {return parseFloat(d.Precipitation) > x});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works. I used + sign in front of those variables.